# How do I create a list of ggplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have these three data frames and this function

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <-
  data.frame(
    x = c("cat", "dog"),
    y = sample(1:100, 20),
    z = seq(ymd("2020-01-01"), ymd("2020-01-20"), by = "1 day")
  )

df2 <-
  data.frame(
    x = c("red", "green"),
    y = sample(1:100, 20),
    z = seq(ymd("2020-01-01"), ymd("2020-01-20"), by = "1 day")
  )

df3 <-
  data.frame(
    x = c("up", "down"),
    y = sample(1:100, 20),
    z = seq(ymd("2020-01-01"), ymd("2020-01-20"), by = "1 day")
  )


dataframes <-
  c("df1", "df2", "df3")

exploreDataFrames <- function(dataframes, sequence = seq_along(dataframes)){
  
  for (i in seq_along(sequence)){
    print(get(dataframes[i]))
    
    gg <-
      get(dataframes[i]) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(z, y, group = 1)) +
      geom_line() +
      facet_wrap(~get(names(get(dataframes[i]))[1]))
    
    return(gg)
  }
}

exploreDataFrames(dataframes[3])
```

I'd like for my function to return a list with three entries:

```
list[1][1] <- name_of_the_dataframe
list[1][2] <- copy_of_the_complete_dataframe
list[1][3] <- ggplot_object
```

My goal is to be able to have a single list and iterate through the ggplot charts, quickly be able to slice it by the name of a particular data frame and pull up the complete dataframe.

What do I need to change about my function to make this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
l = sapply(dataframes, function (dfname) {
      ggplot(get(dfname) , aes(z, y, group = 1)) +
      geom_line() +
      facet_wrap(~get(names(get(dfname))[1]))
    }, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

the data.frame names are then in `names(l)`

```
names(l[1])
# [1] "df1"
```

and the data are in

```
l[[1]]$data

#     x  y          z
#1  cat 68 2020-01-01
#2  dog 39 2020-01-02
#3  cat  1 2020-01-03
#4  dog 34 2020-01-04
#5  cat 87 2020-01-05
#6  dog 43 2020-01-06
#7  cat 14 2020-01-07
#8  dog 82 2020-01-08
#9  cat 59 2020-01-09
#10 dog 51 2020-01-10
#11 cat 85 2020-01-11
#12 dog 21 2020-01-12
#13 cat 54 2020-01-13
#14 dog 74 2020-01-14
#15 cat  7 2020-01-15
#16 dog 73 2020-01-16
#17 cat 79 2020-01-17
#18 dog 37 2020-01-18
#19 cat 83 2020-01-19
#20 dog 97 2020-01-20
```

Comment: How do `sapply` work? I'm unsure how you were able to get the names and the data into the `l` object

Comment: sapply is a kind of loop.  Using `simply = F` forces it to return a list.  Using `USE.NAMES = TRUE` forces it to name each list element after the vector elements

Comment: Awesome! How do you get it to also deliver the data frame?

Comment: ggplot works that magic for you.  Try `gg$data` on any ggplot object.  The plots are stored along with the data that creates them.

Comment: That's so awesome, this is a great answer @dww

Comment: Let's say I had a separate dataframe for each `df` called `diagnostics`. Could I add it to the list so that I could access it like this? l[[1]]$diagnostics

Comment: sure - `l[[1]]$diagnostics = diagnostics` will add this.  The ggplot objects will still work as expected.  Just make sure you don't overwrite an existing element in the ggplot (the names that are already used are: "data"   , "layers"  ,  "scales" ,   "mapping"  , "theme" , "coordinates" "facet",   "plot_env",  "labels")

Answer (score 3):

You need to initiate the whole list before starting to populate it. Since you have a nested level in the list, you need to initiate that "inner" list too:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <-
  data.frame(
    x = c("cat", "dog"),
    y = sample(1:100, 20),
    z = seq(ymd("2020-01-01"), ymd("2020-01-20"), by = "1 day")
  )
df2 <-
  data.frame(
    x = c("red", "green"),
    y = sample(1:100, 20),
    z = seq(ymd("2020-01-01"), ymd("2020-01-20"), by = "1 day")
  )

df3 <-
  data.frame(
    x = c("up", "down"),
    y = sample(1:100, 20),
    z = seq(ymd("2020-01-01"), ymd("2020-01-20"), by = "1 day")
  )


dataframes <-
  c("df1", "df2", "df3")

exploreDataFrames <- function(dataframes, sequence = seq_along(dataframes)){
  
  ll <- list()
  
  for (i in seq_along(sequence)){
    ll[[i]] <- list()
    ll[[i]][[1]] <- dataframes[i]
    # print(get(dataframes[i]))
    ll[[i]][[2]] <- get(dataframes[i])
    ll[[i]][[3]] <- 
      get(dataframes[i]) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(z, y, group = 1)) +
      geom_line() +
      facet_wrap(~get(names(get(dataframes[i]))[1]))
    
  }
  return(ll)
}

out <- exploreDataFrames(dataframes)
```

Answer (score 3):

To return the list the question asks for, create a list to hold the objects before the `for` loop, with the length set to `length(sequence)` and assign the values in the loop.

```
exploreDataFrames <- function(dataframes, sequence = seq_along(dataframes)){
  
  out_list <- vector("list", length = length(sequence))
  for (i in seq_along(sequence)){
    dftmp <- get(dataframes[i])
    print(dftmp)
    
    gg <-
      dftmp %>% 
      ggplot(aes(z, y, group = 1)) +
      geom_line() +
      facet_wrap(~get(names(dftmp)[1]))
    
    out_list[[i]]$data.name <- dataframes[i]
    out_list[[i]]$data <- dftmp
    out_list[[i]]$gg.plot <- gg
  }
  out_list
}

exploreDataFrames(dataframes[3])
```

This will plot the `out_list[[1]]$gg.plot` object, since the function's return value is not assigned to anything, it's returned to the `.GlobalEnv`.